# Throwing error while running the playbook for apache status check

Tags: linux, ansible

I have written the below playbook to check status of apache running:

```
#Demo for testing ansible playbook.
- hosts: lab
  become_user: root
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  #purpose of this task is to check apache running status
        -name: verify apache running status
         shell: if ps -eaf | egrep 'apache|http'|grep -v grep > /dev/null ; then echo 'process_running'; else echo 'process_not_running';fi
         ignore_errors: true
         register: appprocesscheck
 # this task is decision,play will fail/quit,if application is running
        -name: decision point to start patching
         fail: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }} have running Application.Please stop the application first, then attempt patching."
         when: appprocesscheck.stdout == "process_running"
```

And i am getting the below error. please help me in resolving this.

```
[ansibleUser@blb44cehanstst ansible]$ ansible-playbook testweb.yml
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/testweb.yml': line 13, column 15, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        -name: verify apache running status
         shell: if ps -eaf | egrep 'apache|http'|grep -v grep > /dev/null ; then echo 'process_running'; else echo 'process_not_running';fi
              ^ here

[ansibleUser@blb44cehanstst ansible]$
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a YAML syntax error.

Put a space between `-` and `name` in both tasks.

```
- name: verify apache running status
  shell: if ps -eaf | egrep 'apache|http'|grep -v grep > /dev/null ; then echo 'process_running'; else echo 'process_not_running';fi
  ignore_errors: true
  register: appprocesscheck
- name: decision point to start patching
  fail: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }} have running Application.Please stop the application first, then attempt patching."
  when: appprocesscheck.stdout == "process_running"
```

Comment: Thank you, after giving space and adjusting the space for the next modules resolved the issue.